# Detaching/Evicting object tree with non-persisted children

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have an entity managed by Hibernate 4.3.4 which has a 1-many collection of other entities.

During my processing, I have to detach the parent entity (which cascades the detach to the child list).  However when I add a new item to the list which isn't persisted yet and do the detach, I get an IllegalArgumentException ("Non-entity object instance passed to evict") caused by the changes in Hibernate 4.3.0 https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/c8b20660ed56432a946e78794be147422e80ede6 .

Is there a way to cascade detach an object tree which contains non-persisted entities?   I'd prefer to still use the ORM cascade detach mappings if possible, since I have some rather complicated object trees and I don't want to try to build the detach logic myself.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Are you really sure you want to do it like this? It sounds very messy. If you're adding things to the lists and not persisting them at that point, it means you won't be able to persist them later unless you're keeping track of the non-persistent entities separately. Is there a good reason not to persist the ones you're adding at add time? If it's just that you might want to give up on them when the user aborts the mission, you should be using a transaction: start a transaction, persist what you're adding to the child list, and then either commit or roll back the transaction.

Comment: The reason for the detach prior to the persist is that I need to need to run some database queries as part of the validation logic.  Since my database doesn't support nested transactions, these queries were causing premature flushing.

Comment: Can you not perform validation without using transactions, though? You shouldn't need transactions for reading; only for writing. And validation is usually a case just of reading.

Comment: I was under the impression that all database access in Hibernate had to be transactional, even if it was just a read-only transaction.  Those may solve that problem, but there is one other issue.  If the "live" object is still attached, is it ever possible to read the persisted version even in a non-transactional or read-only method?  I think the EntityManager will always just give you a pointer back to the one you already have. (I'm not defending the implementation, I'm sure it could be solved in a different way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out the issue wasn't caused by detaching a non-persisted managed entity, it was caused by detaching a non-managed subclass of the managed entity.  My jaxb demarshalling was giving me a subclass that I wasn't properly downcasting.  I fixed my demarshaller and no longer see the exception.

Thanks for the help and advice in the area.

--Eric